# What should a landlocked country do if blockaded by neighbouring country

Tags: warfare, economy, natural-resources

What should the landlocked country do if there is blockade on FUEL (cooking LPG, petrol, diesel, etc) /FOOD and people of that country are going to starve in near future?

I'm asking this in the context of Nepal (south Asia) in which I currently live and currently India have put blockade (although not officially declared) on fuel/food supply. The road to china is very difficult and recent huge earthquake in April have destroyed that too and it seems very hard to cut through hills to import supplies. The Nepal/India border is an open border where people from either country can pass without a passport.  Nepal has been importing goods and fuel from India from more than 40+ years.  The two countries have also done a treaty regarding export/import of fuel and goods where it states that there will be uninterrupted supply.. I've heard there are also some international rule regarding landlocked country for food/fuel supply.
The Indian government officials have ordered to let the supply go smooth but still the fuel tankers are not allowed to pass through but the container/trucks carrying vegetables (which are decayable) are let to pass through from Indian side.  There is no hatred among the people of both countries as many of Indians and some Nepali make their living working on each other's country.

Reason for blockade:
 Recent Declaration of new constitution 2015, Sept.
I don't know what is the major interest of India..but one thing for sure is that India and China do not have good relation due to border disputes.

Comment: Welcome to the site, johndoes. Can you provide some more information? For instance, what is the time period, what resources does the country have or produce on their own, and what is the nature of the blockade (guards on the roads, a ring of magical fire, etc)?

Comment: "Should" makes the question seem opinion-based. Can you perhaps change this, in addition to @DaaaahWhoosh's suggestions?

Comment: We're on the *worldbuilding* site. Is your fictional world based on the real world of 2015? On a previous century? On a different world? What kind of story do you want to tell? Is are the blockaded people the heroes or the villains of the story? If you clarify that, answers are easier.

Answer (score 1):

Only one answer really: surrender! OK, if it's armed to the teeth then war might not lead to inevitable defeat, but I'd expect any victory to be pyrrhic.

Its mistake is having mismanaged events prior to that point so badly that all its neighbours gang up on the landlocked country. One would expect a politically agile landlocked country always to manage to be allied to at least one of its two or more neighbours. (An enclave isn't really a country: it's got no natural allies, just a surrounding country that doesn't want to annex it quite yet).

I think this answer is pretty universal to any technology level where a blockade can be effective.

Answer (score 0):

Is the land-locked country blockaded by *one* or *more* separate countries?

- [Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switzerland) is landlocked, but their neighbours are different European countries. They have managed to avoid a blockade, even during the WWII period, by keeping on speaking terms with at least some of their neighbours. [Austria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austria) is an even better example, considering how they bordered on the [Iron Curtain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Curtain).
- [Bophuthatswana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bophuthatswana) was landlocked and entirely surrounded by South Africa. Their independence was widely seen as a farce.

You tagged your question with [united-nations](/questions/tagged/united-nations) and [pre-industrial](/questions/tagged/pre-industrial). Should we assume that the landlocked country is a [Landlocked Developing Country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landlocked_developing_countries), but the setting is the modern day?

- If a country is getting starved into submission, that constitutes genocide. Other nations might decide to intervene, but this depends on political realities. Who starves, who blockades, who has friends in high places?
- Have one side or the other been labeled as *terrorist*?

Comment: blockade is effective from last 13 days, and no terrorist have involved. ive edited the question for more information .Thank you

Comment: @johndoes, it doesn't really matter if there were *actual* terrorists. Did one side manage to describe the other as *terrorist* to world media? What does public opinion in Washington have to say? In London? Is the western world wringing their hands or are they taking a stance?

Comment: according to my knowledge and national/local media, the blockade was put because indian government didnt like the constitution recently published. the issue is not internationalized by nepal government because they are afraid that india will put more pressure if the issue is globalized. China,USA and other euro nation are quiet about this but they have supported newly drafted constitution where india have not acc. to their official website statement.

Comment: That sounds as if you're talking about a **real-world** situation. Completely off-topic here.